# Clear dropdown selection on radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, radio-button

I have a set of radio buttons.  When primary is selected, the Primary Company field is hidden.  I would also like to at this time clear the drop down selection.  How can I do this?

```
<p>
        <label>Company Type:</label>
        <label for="primary"><input onclick="javascript: $('#sec').hide('slow');" type="radio" runat="server" name="companyType" id="primary" checked />Primary</label>
        <label for="secondary"><input onclick="javascript: $('#sec').show('slow');" type="radio" runat="server" name="companyType" id="secondary" />Secondary</label>
        <div id="sec">
        <label for="primary_company">Primary Company:</label>
            <%= Html.DropDownList("primary_company", Model.SelectPrimaryCompanies, "** Select Primary Company **") %>
        </div>

    </p>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can clear the selection (that is, select the first option) like so:

```
$("#primary_company").find('option:first')
                     .attr('selected','selected');
```

Comment: +1. but why the `.parent('select');` part? You could just use `.end()`, right?

Comment: @David - that was part of a longer chain to serve an evil purpose. (I pasted too much code from one of my test pages), but now that you point that out, `end` is better than `parent('select')`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass null to the jQuery `val()` method as a nice way to clear a dropdown.

```
$('#primary_company').val(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear the selection completely (so that not even the first element is selected) you could use:

```
$('#primary_company').attr('selectedIndex', '-1');
```

If `#primary_company` is a multiple select box you could use:

```
$('#primary_company option').attr('selected', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#primary_company").find('[selected]').removeAttr("selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best short way that works for me:

```
$("#selectNetBankNameId")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
$("#selectNetBankNameId").trigger("change");
```

Comment: Looks strange to me - this question is seven years old, there are multiple answers that look much nicer than yours, and this should be the "best short way"?